# Maven: Using Exec Maven Plugin and reading project properties

Tags: maven

I've a situation where I've to read a certain properties file and then call an external program.

- For reading the properties file, I'm using the [Properties Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), using `read-project-properties` in the validate phase
- For executing the external program I'm using the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html), calling `exec:exec` goal

However it seems that if I call "mvn exec:exec", the validate phase is not called and as such, the properties are not read.

And in my current scenario, I cannot tie exec:exec to any particular phase (and that is because all other phases have very specific jobs to take care of and what I'm trying to execute with exec:exec does not map to any of these phases. It's more of a standalone thing that I'm trying to do).

The only workaround that I found is to call `mvn validate exec:exec`, which works but my question is:

1. Is it a good idea to mix a phase and a goal as part of a maven execution?
2. Or is there a way for me to make the exec plugin read the properties?

Answer (score 1):

could you use profiles to tie it to a specific phase but *only in certain circumstances / certain environments* ?

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

You could use user, or environment variables, or explicitly use a particular profile, to trigger your choice of profile.  Then in this new profile you can redefine to have a phase all to yourself.

Truly creating a new lifecycle phase of your own seems possible, although not easy :

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLifecycleInMaven?_sscc=t

to be honest, I'd stick with the command line you have, calling validate and then exec.  I don't know of any side effects, and as you say it's just a local, standalone sort of task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Graham. I actually thought of using a separate profile. The only thing that I don't like about this is I'm duplicating my properties plugin (once where it currently is and another within the profile). I was hoping to see whether there was a cleaner solution that going this route.